# Choosing between NSTableView and NSOutlineView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I'd really like to create a table view that is segmented similar to the screen shown [image] ( which is taken from the XCode->Build Phases view ). To be honest, I'm a bit lost on how to start there.

I could use a NSTableView + a custom NSTableCellView that manages the expanding/collapsing behaviour, but I'm entirely not sure if the resizing of an individual row is possible or permitted ( the doc isn't too verbose here ).

The second approach would be to choose a NSOutlineView to accomplish this behaviour, yet it would require some serious subclassing to get where I'd like to go.

So, before I'm doing it wrong again, what would you do? Thanks a lot for your time

– Moritz

Answer (score 2):

I am quite sure that is an NSOutlineView (not sure if is one big outline or 4). The subclassing isn't as hard as it looks. The only item that requires custom drawing is the root element (that's the row with the disclosure triangle.)

Comment: Are you sure that the root element actually "wraps" the subrow content? Or could you point me to the relevant doc here? Thanks a lot!